# Shuffle given words to a matrix

Tags: c#

Let's say I have 3 words: ["mouse", "fish", "cat"]

and a matrix of 4x3

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

and I need to shuffle these words to a matrix with 2 simple rules:

1. consecutive letters of the word must be adjacent either vertically or horizontally
2. you can only use a letter once (meaning - a same letter can't be used to combine 2 words like crosswords)

**A good combination for example (using the 3 words above):**

```
[C][F][I][M]
[A][H][S][O]
[T][E][S][U]
```

What could be the right algorithm to achieve this?
I tried to write it myself, but ended with a half working algorithm

```
void Main(){
    string[,] letterGrid = new string[4,3];

    //initialize array
    for (int i = 0; i < letterGrid.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < letterGrid.GetLength(0); t++)
        {
            letterGrid[t, i] = "-1";
        }
    }

    string[,] validateGrid = (string[,])letterGrid.Clone();

    string[] words = ["mouse","fish","cat"];       

    Random rnd = new Random();
    //prepare grid
    foreach (string word in words)
    {        
        int rndx = rnd.Next(0, letterGrid.GetLength(0));
        int rndy = rnd.Next(0, letterGrid.GetLength(1));
        letterGrid = GetModifiedGrid((string[,])letterGrid.Clone(), word, rndx, rndy, new List<char> { },            
                     (string[,])validateGrid.Clone(), new int[] { -1, -1});
    }
}


//letterGrid & validate starts as a same matrix consists of -1's
//validate matrix simply marks which cells the function already 'visited'
string[,] GetModifiedGrid(string[,] letterGrid, string word, int x, int y, List<char> chars, string[,] validate, int[] lastPos)
{
    var tempLetterGrid = letterGrid;
    var tempValidate = validate;

    if (chars.Count == word.Length)
    {
        return tempLetterGrid;
    }
    else if(tempValidate[x, y] != word[chars.Count].ToString()) {
        tempValidate[x, y] = word[chars.Count].ToString();
        if (tempLetterGrid[x, y] == "-1" && (lastPos[0] == -1 || ((x == lastPos[0] && Mathf.Abs(y - lastPos[1]) < 2) || (y ==    
        lastPos[1] && Mathf.Abs(x - lastPos[0]) < 2))))
        {
            lastPos[0] = x; lastPos[1] = y;
            tempLetterGrid[x, y] = word[chars.Count].ToString();
            chars.Add(word[chars.Count]);
        }
        if(x + 1 < tempLetterGrid.GetLength(0))
            GetModifiedGrid(tempLetterGrid, word, x + 1, y, chars, tempValidate, lastPos);
        if (y + 1 < tempLetterGrid.GetLength(1))
            GetModifiedGrid(tempLetterGrid, word, x, y + 1, chars, tempValidate, lastPos);
        if (x - 1 >= 0)
            GetModifiedGrid(tempLetterGrid, word, x - 1, y, chars, tempValidate, lastPos);
        if (y - 1 >= 0)
            GetModifiedGrid(tempLetterGrid, word, x, y - 1, chars, tempValidate, lastPos);
    }

    return tempLetterGrid;
}
```

Hope someone would be able to help,
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a random feasible shuffle? If yes, should it be uniformly random?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Code should be in the question, not linked-to off-site.  This helps preserve your question's long-term value.

Comment: What topics aligns with this assignment in your course? That feels like recursion/backtracking but depending on what you supposed to exercise maybe something else...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Actually it's not limited to any topic, this is a part of a small program I wrote. It didn't seem so complicated when I initially thought of it though :/

Comment: @sisimendel that's make your life harder :) Unless you have some other restrictions you have to basically try all possible variants and see which ones fit. https://www.bing.com/search?q=recursion%2Fbacktracking should give you some info - basically put a letter, then try add next one at all positions with recursive call for each.